# Writing a configuration file in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [writing to a .php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053947/writing-to-a-php-file)

So I have a config.php file for a CMS that I created from scratch. This file has the structure shown below:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set( "America/Phoenix" );
define( "DB_HOST_USER", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_cms" );
define( "DB_USERNAME", "username" );
define( "DB_PASSWORD", "password" );
define( "CMS_TITLE", "Sample Title");
define( "USERNAME", "cms_user");
define( "PASSWORD", "cms_password");

?>
```

My question is that how can I write into this file and save it to the disk using PHP.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I saw that WordPress uses similar kind of file structure to store user/application configuration as outlined [here](http://phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php.source.html). I was just wondering if I can change above file (config.php) and store new setting in there. For instance, I want to set USERNAME to blog_user (`define( "USERNAME", "blog_user");`). Is it possible to just store this change without rewriting the entire file?

Comment: What do you mean? The PHP file itself is saved to disk already. Are you trying to create an editable config file?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but you can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write to any file as long as the user PHP is running as has write permissions:

```
file_put_contents('filename', '<?php

date_default_timezone_set( "America/Phoenix" );
define( "DB_HOST_USER", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_cms" );
define( "DB_USERNAME", "username" );
define( "DB_PASSWORD", "password" );
define( "CMS_TITLE", "Sample Title");
define( "USERNAME", "cms_user");
define( "PASSWORD", "cms_password");

?>
');
```

Comment: Not quite, I don't want to rewrite the entire file like that. Rather, I was wondering if there was a way to just set one line that was changed.

Comment: @GopalAdhikari I see now.  In that case I recommend that instead of a bunch of constants you create an array or object for configuration.  Then you can serialize it and store it in a file or store it as JSON or YAML or .ini, or one of many other formats.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am trying to do now. I saw in php.net that I could use the serialize and unserialize functions to achieve what I want to do. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to save it to the disk on the server, the following code could be used:

```
$ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
$temp = file_get_contents($ourFileName);
```

Do any necessary changes to $temp where new data can be appended, etc and then:

```
file_put_contents($ourFileName,$temp);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to store configuration data. Try this Stack Overflow: [Fastest way to store easily editable config data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015715/fastest-way-to-store-easily-editable-config-data-in-php)